# MySQL: How to replace all characters in a field except the last 4 chars? (to protect credit card #'s)

Tags: mysql, replace

I've got a mySQL database table called "booking", which contains a column of credit card numbers.  Obviously this is not good or secure, and I really only need the last 4 digits in that field.  I need a mySQL call that will fix this mistake.

Is there a way have one SQL statement that could go through the entire database table and replace all the Visa, Mastercard, Discover card #'s (which are different lengths), and overwrite all but the last 4 chars with XXX's.  Or would I need to write something that loops through each record to do the replace?

The table is called "booking", and the field is called "creditcardnumber"

Comment: yes there are ways, show me what have you tried?

Comment: You have an answer, a good one at that. Check, don't be rude.

Comment: +1 to you as it was a valid question based on practical usage of a LPAD type of a function. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    REPEAT('X', CHAR_LENGTH(card_number) - 4),
    SUBSTRING(card_number, -4)
  ) AS masked_card
FROM
  table_name ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check on this [reference: * SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ec2f/1).
Don't mind the table schema, it's just the sample old data. I changed the first record to a credit card number (duh - it's not starting with 5, 4, or 3 ;) but `LAPD` does the job.

Query:

```
select right(hasha,4),
lpad(right(hasha,4),length(hasha),'x')
from actors
where id = 1
;
```

results:

```
RIGHT(HASHA,4)  LPAD(RIGHT(HASHA,4),LENGTH(HASHA),'X')
3456            xxxxxxxxxxxx3456
```

Comment: @user1258530 Please confirm if the solution helped you out. If so mark as answered so that others can benefit from knowing it worked.